# How to load symbols from Windows DBG file

Tags: ghidra

I'm having trouble getting GHIDRA to load symbols for a Microsoft EXE from an accompanying DBG file.  Perhaps I'm just overlooking some obvious documentation in which case a focussed link would be much appreciated.

Things I've tried:

1. Having both "foo.exe" and "foo.dbg" in the same directory and importing "foo.exe" and auto-analyzing it with defaults.
2. After importing "foo.exe", using "Add to Program" in the CodeBrowser and added "foo.dbg" explicitly.  That suceeds with no errors, but I still can't find the symbols in the "Symbol Tree".

Background:

- Using GHIDRA 9.0.4 installed on Fedora-30 (via ZIP file).
- The EXE is a Delphi-7 EXE built under WinXP (32 bit) with a MAP file and full TD32
  debug in the EXE itself.  I created the DBG file using map2dbg.  This
  is very old, very crusty stuff.  I'm going to create a separate
  question on how to load symbols from a custom file (I've seen
  references but sadly cannot find those menu action in my IDE).

In case this really is a dead end I added a [related question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/21895/29318).

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Wasn't that some awkward proprietary format unrelated to both PDB and the older CV (also with `.dbg` file extension)? In all tools I had to deal with similar cases I had to resort to the map file.