# GHIDRA: How to load symbols from a text (map) file

Tags: ghidra, debugging-symbols

I'm having trouble loading symbols for a very old Delphi-7 EXE.  I posted a separate question regarding loading the DBG file symbols.  Another approach would be to convert the debug symbols (available in a MAP text file) into some other text format and load it.  I see references in the GHIDRA ticketing system to that sort of thing (e.g. [here](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/170)) but I cannot find those actions anywhere in my GHIDRA IDE.

Guidance about where in the GUI to locate those features (and the needed file format) would be greatly appreciated.  Perhaps I need to install some optional component (I just unzipped GHIDRA 9.0.4 onto my Fedora-30 system).

Here is my [related question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/21893/29318).

Comment: Symbols such as textual encoding? Such as ASCII or UTF-8?

Answer (score 2):

It's not certain that the particular map file you have is supported out of the box, but you should be able to use the <kbd>Script Manager</kbd> from the <kbd>Window</kbd> menu in Ghidra (in the Code Browser!).

A good start for your endeavor would likely be the `Ghidra/Features/Python/ghidra_scripts/ImportSymbolsScript.py` script aka `ImportSymbolsScript` (from the Script Manager).

The description of this script is:

> **ImportSymbolsScript.py**
>
> Imports a file with lines in the form "symbolName 0xADDRESS"

Answer (score 1):

Wow that 'ImportSymbolsScript' helped. I 'turned down' that mapfile from

```
...
  Address         Publics by Value

 0001:0000       byte_0
 0001:001A       start
 0001:00D1       __nomain
 0001:00D8       _fclose
 0001:01DA       __fsopen
...
```

into:

```
0001:0000       byte_0
0001:001A       start
0001:00D1       __nomain
0001:00D8       _fclose
0001:01DA       __fsopen
0001:0214       _fopen
0001:0234       __close
...
```

... and modded ImportSymbolsScript.py in GHIDRA 'basic editor' like this:

```
# Imports a file with lines in the form "0xSEGMENT:0xADDRESS symbolName"
# @category Data
# @author 

f = "c:\Tools\!Temp\Portable_VB6\Vs6sp6B\setupsp6.map.txt"
  # f.askFile("Give me a file to open", "Go baby go!")

  # for line in file(f.absolutePath):  # note, cannot use open(), since that is in GhidraScript
for line in file(f):  # note, cannot use open(), since that is in GhidraScript

    pieces        = line.split()
    (segm,offset) = pieces[0].split(":")
    segm          = "1000" # dirty hack !!!
    address       = toAddr(long(segm + offset, 16))
    
    print "creating symbol", pieces[1], "at address", address
    createLabel( address, pieces[1], False )
```

Basically changes are:

1. Changed the input order for pieces[]
2. Added support for segment offset
3. Hard coded file path for better workflow when modding/debugging the script (f = ...)
4. Added that `"1000" +` part into toAddr() to simulate the need segment offset "1000:..."

Well it worked !!!

:)

BEFORE *running the script*:

[image]

AFTER:

[image]